# Check if view controller is the last and set a flag

Tags: ios, swift2, uipageviewcontroller

Currently I am working on a UIPageViewController and I have implemented a function `viewControllerAtIndex_:` which takes an integer as index and returns a UIViewController.

```
func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UIViewController? {
        if contentText.count == 0 || index >= contentText.count {
            return nil
        }

        let contentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IntroContentViewController") as! IntroContentViewController
        contentController.pageIndex = index
        contentController.content = contentText[index]

        currentViewController = contentController
        return contentController
    }
```

But now, I want to set a property of that view controller being returned. Simple enough, I could use `contentController.showsButton = true`, but I only want that to happen when this is the last view controller.

I have tried using `if index >= contentText.count {}` and `if index == contentText.count{}`, but it only returns false for me.

How would I check that, given `index` and `contentText.count` which supplies the number of child view controllers for the page view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but if I get it right, you can use the fallowing check.

```
if contentText.count - 1 == index {
    contentController.showsButton = true
}
```